# Disable dracut-modules-growroot on Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7

I'm testing Amazon linux since it comes with the enhanced networking goodies we want right out of the box (relieving us of the task of making our own AMIs).  However, it comes with dracut-modules-growroot which has an unwanted behaviour - resizing of root partition to use the whole volume.  Does anyone know of a way to disable this on boot (without modifying the underlying AMI) or force an instance to use only a specific amount of the volume?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something the hard way.  If you don't want your root partition to be larger than size x, why would you make the root volume larger than size x?  Why would you not attach a second volume, instead, when creating the instance?  Or, if you insist... why would you not create an instance from the AMI, remove the package, make any other desired changes, then create your own "standard" AMI from the instance, to launch future instances from?

Comment: Very valid questions.  It's simpler in our automation to use one ebs volume over 2, but we prefer to setup LVM with several partitions.  The advantage we're looking for from the Amazon Linux AMIs is not having to monitor an AMI and recreate ours when changes are added.  Having said, that, I think we'll go with adding a second volume.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: Your comment confirms something I suspected from the initial question: *"not having to monitor an AMI and recreate ours when changes are added."*  This is not an issue, if I understand your concern, because AMIs never change.  They're frozen.  When changes are made to Amazon Linux (or anything else that "ships" as an AMI), they are published as a different AMI, with a different AMI ID... so there is no need to monitor a given AMI for changes.

Comment: Good point Michael!  THanks for the information!